# Reversing all bits in a variable with PHP

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I need to read a binary file in PHP, search for a location, reverse their bits and manipulate the result.

currently my code looks like this:

```
$src_file = "firmware/shapeshifter_v2.02.jic";
$offset = 983195;

if ($src_handle = fopen($src_file,"rb")) {
  fseek($src_handle, $offset);
  $src_content = fread($src_handle, 1024);
  fclose($src_handle);

  $src_content = $src_content & 128 >> 7 + $src_content & 64 >> 5 + $src_content & 32 >> 3 + $src_content & 16 >> 1 + $src_content & 8 << 1 + $src_content & 4 << 3 + $src_content & 2 << 5 + $src_content & 1 << 7;

  print bin2hex($src_content);
}
```

I'm trying to reverse the all the bits from the chunk with an algorythm found in this forum, but I cannot reverse more than one bit with it.

Do you have an efficient solution to **reverse all** the bits in a binary variable in PHP?

this is how it looks like with a manual conversion:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated note: [Stack Overflow is not a *forum*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums)

Comment: `str_split`, `array_map`, `implode`.

Comment: You're reading 1024 bytes, not just a single number. What do you expect something like `$src_contents & 128` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I managed to reverse the bits of a byte in PHP using the following algorithm:

```
$binary = decbin(ord($char));
$binary = str_pad($binary, 8, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
$binary = strrev($binary);
$reversednumber = bindec($binary);
$reversed = pack("C",$reversednumber);
```

first, convert the byte to an int and get the binary representation. Then it fills it with 0 until it's 8 chars long.
then it reverses the string and assemble the string back to a number. The final step is to pack it as an one byte string again.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading 1024 bytes into a string, not a single byte into a number. Use:

```
$src_content = ord(fread($src_handle, 1));
```

This will read one byte, then convert it from a character to its numeric code. Then you can reverse the bits in this number as you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse bits in a binary value, Use like :

```
<?php 
$binaryValue = 101010;
echo strtr($binaryValue,[1,0]);
?>
```

It will output : 010101

Hope it helps. Thanks.