# How to concatenate bits of several bytes in PHP

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

My self-study in [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) and here has so far not enabled me to find any approach! My experiments with operators like `&` and `>>` or `<<` I do not want to show here - too embarrassing!

The starting point are arrays of different lengths with integer values (always 8-bit).

So for instance:

```
[178, 89, 1]
```

Their binary coded equivalent...

```
10110010, 01011001, 00000001
```

should be, least significant bit first,...

```
01001101, 10011010, 10000000
```

concatenated:

```
010011011001101010000000
```

Can someone explain the procedure to me step by step, so that I understand the **bit operations** in php?

Thank you

Post scriptum:
I don't want to solve the problem with string operations (I can do that - but it's terribly slow!), but with bit operations.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077613/reversing-all-bits-in-a-variable-with-php for how to reverse the bits in a byte. Do you need to know anything more to solve the puzzle?

Comment: I explicitly asked for bit operations, not for conversion into strings, string operations and backwards

Comment: how output should be represented? as 3-byte integer or 24 char string?

Comment: As int not string

Comment: You eventually have to convert it to a string, since you may have too many bits to fit in a computer integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you need something like this:

```
<?php
$array = [178, 89, 1];

$output = 0;
foreach ($array as $v) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $output = ($output << 1) | ($v & 1);
        $v = $v >> 1;
    }
}

echo $output . " " . str_pad(decbin($output), 24, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

now step by step:

1. for every element in input array we're getting 0th bit (less significant) - `$v & 1`
2. output variable is shifted left to provide space for this bit `$output << 1`
3. bit is set to the most right position in output variable `|` part
4. we shift variable to the right, so 1st bit becomes 0th
5. repeat for the rest

Answer (score 2):

Use, [decbin()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php) but you will need to `0` pad left, else `00000001` will become `1` again.

One way to do it would be to use [array_reduce()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), though you could loop over the array many ways.

```
<?php
$array = [178, 89, 1];

echo array_reduce($array, function ($acc, $byte) {
   return $acc.strrev(str_pad(decbin($byte), 8, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT));
})
```

Result: `010011011001101010000000`

https://3v4l.org/D4qGr

Comment: If you want the result to be represented as an integer, take
bindec (array_reduce ($ array, function ($ acc, $ byte) {...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function dec2bin_i($decimal_i)
{
 bcscale(0);

 $binary_i = '';
 do
  {
   $binary_i = bcmod($decimal_i,'2') . $binary_i;
   $decimal_i = bcdiv($decimal_i,'2');
  } while (bccomp($decimal_i,'0'));

 return($binary_i);
}
//empty output string
$output = '';
//define array
$array = [178, 89, 1];
//loop array values
foreach($array as $value){
    //convert to binary and concatenate
    $output .= dec2bin_i($value);
}
//show output
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: I used function from another post

Comment: but there a concatenate part , is extra?

Comment: Thx, but: I explicitly asked for bit operations, not for conversion into strings, string operations and backwards